# Using Mockito, but real method is being called

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am making unit tests in my spring boot project and I am using mockito to mock instances. CalculeMajStockServiceImpl is the class I want to test and getEtatTranche is the method I want to test.
This is my test class.The problem here is that the real getDateCouplageParCycleEtParTrancheEtParLibelle method is called.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class CalculeMajStockServiceImplTest {
     
    @Mock
    private ServiceBddProxy serviceBddProxy;

    @Mock
    private ServiceDataExcelProxy serviceDataExcelProxy;

    @Mock
    private ServiceAccessDonneesProxy serviceAccessDonneesProxy;

    @Mock
    private ParseFichierC3poServiceImpl parseFichierC3poServiceImpl;

    @Mock
    private ParseFichierRealiseRteServiceImpl parseFichierRealiseRteServiceImpl;

    @Mock
    private ParseFichierHebdoServiceImpl parseFichierHebdoServiceImpl;

    @Spy
    CalculeMajStockServiceImpl calculeMajStockServiceImpl = Mockito.spy(CalculeMajStockServiceImpl.class);

    @Before
    void setMockOutput() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void getEtatTranche() {
        Date dateExtrapolation = new Date(2020, 05, 06);
        Date dateDeCouplage = new Date(2020, 04, 06);
        Date dateCourante = new Date(2020, 03, 20);
        Date dateCoouplageLibellePrecedent = new Date(2020, 03, 19);
        Long idLibellePrecedent = 1L;
        String trancheCode = "BELV1";
        int numCycle = 23;

        LibelleDto libelle = new LibelleDto();
        libelle.setDateCourante(dateCourante);
        
        LibelleDto libellePrecedent = new LibelleDto();
        libellePrecedent.setDateCourante(dateCourante);
        // CAS OU dateCourante>=dateCouplageLibellePrecedent et
        // dateExtrapolation>dateCouplage
         doReturn(dateCoouplageLibellePrecedent).when(calculeMajStockServiceImpl)
                .getDateCouplageParCycleEtParTrancheEtParLibelle(Mockito.anyLong(), Mockito.anyString(),
                        Mockito.anyInt());
        Integer calculated = this.calculeMajStockServiceImpl.getEtatTranche(dateDeCouplage,
                trancheCode, numCycle, libellePrecedent, new Date());
         verify(calculeMajStockServiceImpl).getDateCouplageParCycleEtParTrancheEtParLibelle(Mockito.anyLong(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyInt());
    //  verify(calculeMajStockServiceImpl).findLibelleById(Mockito.anyLong());
        Integer expected = 2;
        assertEquals(expected, calculated);}
}
```

and this is the method i want to test

```
@Override
    public int getEtatTranche(Date dateCouplage, String trancheCode, int numCycle,
            LibelleDto libellePrecedent, Date dateCourante) {
        int etatTranche = 0;

        if (dateCourante != null && dateCouplage != null) {
            if (dateCouplage.compareTo(dateCourante) > 0) {
                Date dateCouplageLibellePrecedent = this.getDateCouplageParCycleEtParTrancheEtParLibelle(
                        libellePrecedent.getId(), trancheCode, numCycle);
                if (dateCouplageLibellePrecedent != null && dateCourante != null
                        && dateCouplageLibellePrecedent.compareTo(libellePrecedent.getDateCourante()) <= 0) {
                    etatTranche = 2;
                } else {
                    etatTranche = 3;
                }
            }

            else {
                etatTranche = 1;
            }
        }
        return etatTranche;
    }
```

Comment: Try using `@Mock` for `CalculeMajStockServiceImpl`

Answer (score 1):

This creates a spy instance of `CalculeMajStockServiceImpl` *without* injecting mocks.

```java
@Spy
CalculeMajStockServiceImpl calculeMajStockServiceImpl = Mockito.spy(CalculeMajStockServiceImpl.class);
```

You may try

```java
@InjectMocks 
CalculeMajStockServiceImpl calculeMajStockServiceImpl;
```

And then explicitly define a spy inside `@Before` method.

Mockito does not support injecting mocks into spies.

Note: If you are using `MockitoJUnitRunner`, you don't have explicitly call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`

Comment: even when i tried injectMocks i always have null even whe i debug i see that calculeMajStockServiceImpl is null and even other attribute.By the way CalculeMajStockServiceImpl  is annotated with @service

Comment: @fbmfatma It may be so  if `CalculeMajStockServiceImpl` does not a have proper constructor (i.e it has `@Autowired` fields or setters). Consider adding a constructor or using `@MockBean` if you're using Spring.

Answer (score 0):

The sollution is to add @spy  @InjectMocks
CalculeMajStockServiceImpl calculeMajStockServiceImpl;